# Use annotation other than XstreamAlias to serialize an object with XStream

Tags: java, serialization, xstream

I have a java class in which members are annotated with the XstreamAlias annotation. Under some conditions I would like to output the same class (and its members recursively) with different annotations.
How can I ask Xstream to use method/class annotations that are not the @XstreamAlias annotation?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot make XStream to use different annotations, but you can define different aliases in code.

```
@XStreamAlias("abc")
public class Abc
{
    @XStreamAlias("bb")
    public String a;
}
```

When you serialize above class with annotations you will get following xml

```
<abc>
  <bb>something</bb>
</abc>
```

When you disable annotations and define new aliases

```
XStream xstream = new XStream();
xstream.autodetectAnnotations(false);
xstream.alias("xxx", Abc.class);
xstream.aliasField("ccc", Abc.class, "a");
```

you will get different xml output

```
<xxx>
  <ccc>something</ccc>
</xxx>
```

---

**List of available alias methods:**

Alias a Class to a shorter name to be used in XML elements.

```
public void alias(String name, Class type)
```

Alias a type to a shorter name to be used in XML elements. Any class that is assignable to this type will be aliased to the same name.

```
public void aliasType(String name, Class type)
```

Alias a Class to a shorter name to be used in XML elements. defaultImplementation represents default implementation of type to use if no other specified.

```
public void alias(String name, Class type, Class defaultImplementation)
```

Alias a package to a shorter name to be used in XML elements.

```
public void aliasPackage(String name, String pkgName)
```

Create an alias for a field name.

```
public void aliasField(String alias, Class definedIn, String fieldName)
```

Create an alias for an attribute

```
public void aliasAttribute(String alias, String attributeName)
```

Create an alias for a system attribute. XStream will not write a system attribute if its alias is set to `<code>null</code>`. However, this is not reversible, i.e. deserialization of the result is likely to fail afterwards and will not produce an object equal to the  originally written one.

```
public void aliasSystemAttribute(String alias, String systemAttributeName)
```

Create an alias for an attribute.

```
public void aliasAttribute(Class definedIn, String attributeName, String alias)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What would be the API (and not the annotation) for omitting a field/class from the output xml?

Comment: I think it is `omitField(Class definedIn, string fieldName)`

Comment: If you have found my answer helpful/correct then please upvote/accept it. [How does accepting an answer work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)